# I can't open a UV texture image on mac

Tags: osx

I was trying to make the sims hair CC.
But I can't open any texture image!
I tried all sizes and all type of image but it just can't be opened.
when I try to open it,it stoped working and my cursor turned into loading color wheel.
other applications are all normal and working.only blender crashed.(maybe)

I hope some one can help.

I'm using MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015)

2.2 GHz Intel Core i7

8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

Macintosh HD

Intel HD Graphics 6000 1536 MB

and blender 2.78
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange. Is it only with *that* project that it happens, or is this a problem with *all* of your projects? Do the images open and display normally in your other applications (image editors, etc)? Some ideas: Try moving your project to a file path without Chinese text (Blender supports Asian language file paths, so this should not be the cause of the problem - it's just something to test). You could try [upgrading to 2.79b](https://www.blender.org/download/).

Comment: You can also launch Blender through Terminal to see console output. The error causing Blender to crash might be shown in the console log. To do this, locate Blender.app in your Applications folder, right click on it and *Show Package Contents*. Navigate to `/Contents/MacOS/blender` and when you double-click **blender** it will launch from Terminal.

Comment: It happend on all project,and my texture image can be opened normally on other applications.

Comment: I tried the way you said but it doesn't work:(

Comment: I just copied my file to my another macbook pro,installed blender and tried.It's same result.

Comment: Can you **pack** and then post your .blend file to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)? Then others can take a look and try to figure out what's going on.

Comment: I uploaded it. But it says ''Files may take some time to process'' What does it means?

Comment: Is your file really large? If it's too big, you can try removing some of the textures first.

Comment: It's 2.1MB. I already remove all textures.

Comment: That's very unusual. I've never seen that happen. Maybe whatever is causing Blender to crash is also causing the file not to validate when uploaded. You can try sharing through [PasteAll](http://pasteall.org/blend/) instead (hosting is temporary though).

Comment: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51914 here! thank you

Comment: I was able to download and open your .blend, *and* I was able to load a custom texture into the hair meshes (1024x1024 PNG with alpha). *(Blender 2.79b, MacBook Pro 15-inch 2015 macOS Sierra)* At this point it's looking like a problem specific to your hardware. But don't give up yet. See if you can create a new .blend and then *Append* the various mesh objects one by one into the new file. I expect to be busy for the next several days and might not check Stack Exchange during that time, but let me know how it goes.

Comment: I'll try! Thank you so much!

Comment: hello,I tried it on windows system.and it can work normally,I think problem is on my macOS,anyway I decided to work on windows,thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm glad it's working for you now! It's strange that it didn't work on your Mac. If you can describe how to reproduce the problem it might be worth filing a bug report. I wasn't able to reproduce it on my Mac.